# Remove (ex.vat) label on the item list except in Sub Total (ex. vat) label in Thank you Page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any solution to remove the **ex. vat** label on the item list on thank you page, except in Sub total

In the Screenshot below the highlighted green should be removed.
[image: Heres the screenshot the highlighted green should be removed]

Thank you.

Comment: You can inspect your cart page and change the product list row's `woocommerce-price-suffix` css property to `display: none;` in your theme's custom css.

Answer (score 0):

it solved with this css code :D

```
.woocommerce-Price-taxLabel.tax_label{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same Tax setting, problems solve automatically.

[image: Tax setting sample image]